# RUN FAILED (exit value -1.073.740.940 )

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm quite new to c++ and netbeans and have quite a problem here and I can't put my finger on what the error might be. 
Building is always succesful but I get a RUN FAILED (exit value -1.073.740.940, total time: 2s) error, when running my program. My code:

Arraylist.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace hfu {

class Arraylist {
private:
    double* members;
    int size;
public:
    Arraylist(int);
    ~Arraylist();
    Arraylist(const Arraylist&);
    double get(int) const;
    void set(int, double);
    Arraylist& operator=(const Arraylist&);
    //float operator[](int);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Arraylist&);
};
}
```

Arraylist.cpp:

```
#include "Arraylist.hpp"
#include <exception>


namespace hfu {

Arraylist::Arraylist(int i) : size(i), members(new double[size]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        set(i, 0);
    }
}

Arraylist::~Arraylist() {
    delete members;
}

Arraylist::Arraylist(const Arraylist& other) : size(other.size), members(new double[other.size]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        set(i, other.get(i));
    }

}

double Arraylist::get(int i) const {
    if (i < 0 || i >= size) {
        throw (std::exception());
    } else {
        return members[i];
    }
}

void Arraylist::set(int i, double value) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= size) {
        throw (std::exception());
    } else {
        members[i] = value;
    }
}

Arraylist& Arraylist::operator=(const Arraylist& other) {
    size = other.size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        set(i, other.get(i));
    }
    return *this;
}

//    float Arraylist::operator [](int index) {
//        return members[index];
//   }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Arraylist& list) {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size; i++) {
        os << "[" << list.get(i) << "]";
    }
    return os;
}
```

}

main.cpp:

```
#include "Arraylist.hpp"

int main() {
try {
    auto a1 = hfu::Arraylist(10);
    std::cout << a1 << std::endl;
    auto a2 = hfu::Arraylist(10);
    std::cout << a2 << std::endl;
    auto a3 = hfu::Arraylist(10);
    std::cout << a3 << std::endl;

}
catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}

}
```

I can create 2 objects of Arraylist.... but not more, it will print the first two and then fail.... but when I create shorter lists, say 3 with only size one... it will work... so I think it might be something with the memory... but I'm at a loss. Ideas?

Thanks a lot!

btw: I'm using netbeans 8.2 and mingw g++ 6.1.0

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Exit value `-1.073.740.940` is better understood as exit value `0xc0000374`, which is a Windows core error code (`NTSTATUS`) that's documented to mean "[a heap has been corrupted](http://errorco.de/win32/ntstatus-h/status_heap_corruption/0xc0000374/)".  In other words: you have a memory corruption bug.  Apply `valgrind`.  If you can't use `valgrind` get a real computer.

Comment: ... Skimming through your code, your copy constructor has an obvious bug in it: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {` That ought to be `i < size`, shouldn't it?  I'm not sure this can cause the problem you describe but I don't see anything else obviously wrong.

Comment: oh well, that was just for testing.. sorry, it is in fact i < size. but i don't use it anywhere.

Comment: it's running through the debugger just fine....

Comment: @JaninePolster _"it's running through the debugger just fine"_ I doubt that. Well, a difference could be variable initialization done with debug builds. Is your program build in release mode?

Comment: @JaninePolster, try this `private: 
  int size;
  double* members;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization order of the member variables is defined by the order of their definitions *in the class*, not by their order in the initializer list. As a matter of fact, your compiler should be giving you *"hfu::Arraylist::size will be initialized after"* warnings.

So in your case, `members` gets initialized before `size`, thus `new double[size]` is called when `size` is still garbage. In my case it simply causes `std::bad_array_new_length` to be thrown. In your case, things go worse and your application crashes.

So the solution is to change

```
class Arraylist {
private:
    double* members;
    int size;
```

to

```
class Arraylist {
private:
    int size;
    double* members;
```